# Dynamic Aura:Id inside Aura:Iteration

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have a component which will display a list of records in the table and user can edit and update each row.

Issue: Since I have static aura:id inside aura:iteration, whenever I'm trying to edit and save the second record without refreshing the page after updating the first record, it is throwing the error on component.get().

Ex Component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.freightChargesAir}" var="fcair" indexVar="index"> 
   <tr class="slds-hint-parent"> 
     <td class="slds-truncate slds-size--1-of-10" data-label="Name" >                                        
         <UI:inputText aura:id="frequencyEdit" value="{!fcair.Frequency__c}"></UI:inputText>
     </td>
     <td class="slds-truncate slds-size--21" data-label="dest"> 
         <a tabindex="{!index}" onclick="{!c.saveFreightEdit}" id="{!fcair.Id}">
            <lightning:icon iconName="action:record" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
         </a>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

</aura:iteration>

Ex Controller:

```
saveFreightEdit: function(component, event, helper) {

    var recId =  event.target.id;
    var frequencyfind = component.find("frequencyEdit");
    var frequency = frequencyfind.get("v.value");  //Getting error here on second record save if page is not refreshed
    //logics goes on...

}
```

Since aura:id doesn't support dynamic Id's, I couldn't get this done as expected.

I tried replacing the UI:InputText with Lighting:input and ID attribute to get the value from DOM element but ended in no luck. Getting undefined error if I use document.getElementById.

I faced similar issue with document.getElementsByClassName as well.

Is there any way to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the Id of the record, you can just use Array#find.

```
var freqRow = component.get("v.freightChargesAir").find(row => row.Id === event.target.id);
// ...freqRow.Frequency__c has the edited value
```

From here, you have the full object that represents your record.

Comment: Thanks for this easiest answer and this works like a wonder. I got to know there is something like this existing in javascript lightning controller. Thank you so much. But the only problem is, whenever I try to edit and save the row(record) which is already edited and saved, am getting `[component.find(...).get is not a function]` error.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen My answer was to grab all the rows of data stored in the attribute "freightChargesAir", then find the specific row using Array#find. **Incorrect**: `component.find(...).get(...)` **Correct**: `component.get(...).find(...)`.

Comment: My apologies sfdcfox. It is due to the code logic I have in the bottom of the function. I corrected that issue and ofcourse yeah it is working very well without any issues. Thanks for the answer. I got to know the new thing. Marking this as best answer.

Comment: Hi @mohammedazarudeen, I'm facing the same kind of issue.Mine is a picklist field instead of a text field.Upon doing this "component.get().find(row => row.Id === event.target.id);" I get Undefined in my console.Can you please guide me in this.

Comment: @jayasuriyajanarthan It sounds like you have a different issue? I recommend asking a new question so you can get the help you need.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Will post my question.